# Sum of members of Geometric progression

Tags: geometric-progressions

They want me to find the 3 members of a decreasing geometric progression. And I am given that let them be $a,b,c$ $a+b+c=14$ and that $a^2+b^2+c^2=84$

I tried to express everything with the first so $a+a.q+a.q^2=14$

$a(1+q+q^2)=14$

$a^2(1+q^2+q^4)=84$ (I tried to solve these to equations but couldn't.
I can clearly see that the members are probably $8,4,2$ and $q=0,5$ but I can't show it.

Comment: Better use $a/q+a+aq$ which makes it much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
a(1+r+r^2)&=14&&\cdots (1)\\
a^2(1+r^2+r^4)&=84\\\Rightarrow a^2(1+r+r^2)(1-r+r^2)&=84&&\cdots (2)\\\\
(2)\div (1):\qquad\qquad\qquad 
a(1-r+r^2)&=6&&\cdots(3)\\\\
((1)- (3))\div2:\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \;\; 
ar&=4&&\cdots (4)\\
((1)+ (3))\div2:\qquad\qquad\qquad 
a(1+r^2)&=10&&\cdots (5)\\\\
(5)\div (4):\qquad\qquad\qquad
\frac {1+r^2}{r}&=\frac 52\\
2r^2-5r+2&=0\\
(2r-1)(r-2)&=0\\
\because r<0 \text{  (decreasing GP)  }\qquad\therefore r&=\frac 12\\
a&=8
\end{align}$$
Hence GP is 
$$\color{red}{8,4,2}$$

Answer (score 1):

An interesting trick comes from noticing that $\frac{1+q^2+q^4}{1+q+q^2} = 1-q+q^2$, hence
$$ a(1+q+q^2) = 14,\qquad a^2(1+q^2+q^4)=84 $$
lead to $a(1-q+q^2)=\frac{84}{14}=6$, then to $2aq=14-6=8$, hence $aq=4$ and $q$ is a root of
$$ 1+q+q^2 = 14\cdot\frac{q}{4} $$
so the only chances are $q=2$ and $q=\frac{1}{2}$ and it is straightforward to finish.